# How to configure Angular 2 router to run from /src subfolder

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

Basically I'm trying to make two distinct subfolders in my project, `src` and `dist`. Here are the important bits in my app:

- root folder: `C:\Server\htdocs\`
- app folder: `C:\Server\htdocs\src`
- **index.html** has `<base href="/">`
- Using `router 3.0.0-rc.1`

Part of **system.config.js**

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'src/',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
};

var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

**routes.ts**

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: WebComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'editor',
        component: EditorComponent
    }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [provideRouter(routes)];
```

If I try to access: `http://localhost/src/` the root path for the app, I get the following error:

`platform-browser.umd.js:937 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'src'`

How should I configure router to work under the `src/` subfolder?

**Edit**

If I try `<base href="src/">` I get error:

`zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:10080/src/src/src/main.js 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:478 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:10080/src/src/src/main.js`

If I try `<base href="/src/">` , with slashes in front and back, I get error:

`zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:10080/src/src/main.js 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:478 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:10080/src/src/main.js`

**Edit 2 - index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="src/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App 0.1.0</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/main.css">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/template/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="/src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <app>
        <div class="intro-logo"></div>
    </app>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 3**

I tried this combination:

```
<base href="/src/">
<script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

Now I get this error:

`GET http://localhost:10080/systemjs.config.js` (not found)

**Edit 4**

Eventually I used:

```
<base href="/src/">
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

**system.config.js**

```
var map = {
    'app':                        '',
    '@angular':                   '../node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '../node_modules/rxjs'
};
```

Router error is gone, and `routerLink` works fine. However, if I access the `http://localhost:10080/src/admin/` route directly, I get shown the folder contents, I guess I have to configure an URL rewrite in Xampp.

**Edit 5**

I used the following **.htaccess** file in order to redirect to **index.html** so that the router can route to the proper path when requesting pages via url.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^src/admin$     src/index.html    [NC,L]    # Admin
RewriteRule    ^src/editor$    src/index.html    [NC,L]    # Editor
```

Comment: You tried to set base-href url as <base href="/src/"> ?

Comment: I made an edit just before reading your comment, regarding this scenario.

Comment: Could you show your index.html file?

Comment: I have added the index.html content as edit #2

Comment: Look - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp
If you set base url tag, you also have to change paths to all included files (js scripts, css stylesheets), so now your <script src="/src/systemjs.config.js"></script> is just <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script> if you set base url to '/src/'.

Comment: I just tried this, not working... check edit #3

Comment: Just <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>, remove slash '/'.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Would you like to write a short answer so I can choose it as the good answer?

Comment: All my pleasure. I wrote short answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base tag specifies the base URL for **all relative paths** in a document. Change:

```
<base href="/">
```

Into:

```
<base href="/src/">
```

Also make sure to correct every path to all stylesheets & js files.